# Deformation on slow drawing Android/Java

Tags: java, android, paint

I need to draw a line with sharp edges with my finger what works great if I move my finger fast, but when moving slow the line gets deformated like below. It should look like if I just moved a rectangle.

[Image when moving fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apbhT.png)

[Image when moving slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecl48.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    touchX = event.getX();
    touchY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    startX = touchX;
                    startY = touchY;
                    somethingWasDrawn = false;
                    break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath.reset();
                    break;
```

drawPaint gets initialized like this:

```
        Paint drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWith);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
```

Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Maybe set a move distance threshold where you don't add to the path unless they've passed the threshold, say 3dip or something like that, as it;s likely the points are so close together it's having trouble joining them

Comment: not the perfekt solution but much better - thank you!